# Split data in 1 column while retaining data in other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-365

I have data that comes in to me daily that I am manually separating column B (Node Area) into individual rows. I am looking for help creating a solution that will retain the rest of data in the row and split out Column B by carriage return.

I have been playing with `Power Query` as I think that would be the way to go, but when I am trying to split column B by Carriage Return delimiter, nothing happens. Not sure if I missed something, but the m-code is below

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Available Days", type any}, {"Node Area", type text}, {"Tech Name", type text}, {"Cell Number", type text}, {"MA", type text}, {"Title", type text}, {"Work Type", type text}, {"Pick Up Location", type text}, {"Pickup Time", type time}, {"Truck #", type any}, {"MT Skill Sets", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Node Area", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(#)(cr)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Node Area"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Node Area", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

I have also been looking at creating a formula in excel this works to split column B only `TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(B3,CHAR(10)))`, but not sure what else I need. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Starting Data

| Available Days | Node Area | Tech Name | Cell Number | MA | Title | Work Type | Pick Up Location | Pickup Time | Truck # | MT Skill Sets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/20/23 | HO006 HO033 | Paul Johnson | + 1 (555) 123-4567 | WNY | MT | Daytime Work | Frisby Street | 11:15 AM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO008 HO019 HO047 HO048 HO049 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO017 | Chad Dutch | + 1 (555) 987-6543 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |

After Editing

| Available Days | Node Area | Tech Name | Cell Number | MA | Title | Work Type | Pick Up Location | Pickup Time | Truck # | MT Skill Sets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/20/2023 | HO006 | Paul Johnson | + 1 (555) 123-4567 | WNY | MT | Daytime Work | Frisby Street | 11:15 AM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO033 | Paul Johnson | + 1 (555) 123-4567 | WNY | MT | Daytime Work | Frisby Street | 11:15 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO008 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO019 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO047 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO048 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO049 | Brad Smith | + 1 (555) 867-5309 | WNY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:00 PM |  | All of the above |
| 7/20/2023 | HO017 | Chad Dutch | + 1 (555) 987-6543 | ENY | MT | Overnight Work | Frisby Street | 11:30 PM |  | All of the Above |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring data into powerquery with data .. from table/range ...

right click the Node Area column

split column .. by delimiter ... with these options (note [x]rows )

[image]

it will probably populate the correct code itself, but if #(lf) does not work, try #(cr)

file .. close and load ... back into excel

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride  Power Query is still new to me